# ConcurrentRunsExceedsException in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

This is my glue configuration :
MaxConcurrentRuns : 3
AllocatedCapacity : 30 ( MaxCapactity: 30)

I am trying to load 16 files and Glue is creating 3 instance for first 3 files and completing successfully then in next batch (3 files) 1 or 2 glue jobs are not triggered and getting ConcurrentRunsExceedsExcpetion.
This is not consistent error or for specific files but in 16 runs 2 or 3 jobs are giving this error .
Please suggest or advice what will be the issue here and can fix it ?

Comment: As the error indicate this issue is happening because Glue is trying to launch new instance while there are already 3 instances of your job executing/running. How are you launching these jobs? Are you waiting for the previous job runs to be completed before starting a new instance?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . We added sleep for 30 sec before launching 3 new instances and now it is working fine

Comment: Can you mark this as answered if it helped?

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicate this issue is happening because Glue is trying to launch new instance while there are already 3 instances of your job executing/running.

You need to make sure that you are not running them in parallel which will exceeds the concurrent runs configured. This can be fixed by staggering job calls by few seconds.